# Error while running any ruby related commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

Gives me this error twice:

```
rbenv: version `2.1.1' is not installed
rbenv: version `2.1.1' is not installed
```

When I do `rvenv versions` it gives me this output

```
  system
  1.9.3-p547
* 2.1.1
```

Not sure what wrong I'm doing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding these two lines inside my bashrc file solved my problem.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Answer (score 0):

try `rbenv shell 2.1.1` to set the environment in for your current shell

Comment: thanks but this didn't help. Am I missing something?